# Escaping characters when calling ssh from windows

Tags: windows, linux, command-line, ssh

I need to call an ssh command from a Windows command prompt that will execute a command on a remote Linux machine. The command accepts two string parameters, one of which can potentially be multi-lined. Basically, my call looks something like this:

```
ssh user@server command parameter1 parameter2
```

This fails miserably when there are spaces in the parameters.
I've tried to escape the parameters with `'`, but those are stripped by the Windows box, and the Linux then mangles the parameters.
I've tried also `"`, and those ok by the Windows box, but the Linux just ignores them.
The version where I use both, like this

```
ssh user@server command "'para meter 1'" "'para meter 2'"
```

kinda-sorta works, but now I have the problem of in-line quotes. Is there any standard way that I would make both Linux and Windows understand both spaces, single and double quotes?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go ....

```
ssh user@server date "--date='TZ=\"America/Los_Angeles\" 09:00 next Fri'"
```

prints

```
Fri Aug 17 16:00:00 UTC 2012
```

The important thing is that windows command prompt takes " as quote character and you can escape enclosed "s with \ making this one parameter.

Hope this helps.